# Deleting '\' and other special characters from a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, special-characters

First post here so sorry if this is rookie material.  I'm trying to hack away a complicated array into a string and I'm having trouble deleting '\' and '"' characters.  Any help is appreciated.

Currently I have this:

```
"\"-6,\", \"\\\"-3-\\\", \\\"1\\\"\", \"\\\"3-\\\", \\\"5\\\"\", \"\\\"7-\\\", \\\"11\\\"\", \"\\\"14-\\\", \\\"15\\\"\", \"\\\"17-\\\", \\\"20\\\"\""
```

When I'd like to have this:

```
"-6, -3-, 1, 3-, 5, 7-, 11, 14-, 15, 17-, 20"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `each` and removing any non-desired character within every value in the main array, like:

```
array.each{|x| x.gsub!(/[^0-9-,]/, '') }.to_s.gsub!(',,', ',')
# => ["-6,-3-,1,3-,5,7-,11,14-,15,17-,20"]
```

This takes the main array and for each value it replaces any character that's not numeric, nor a hyphen nor a comma with `''` using the `/[^0-9-,]/` regex and the `gsub!` method, and the second `gsub!` is to replace the double comma that remains from the first modification.

I know isn't so elegant, but could help you.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  I was hoping there was an easy way to delete these types of characters from a string (like how you can easily delete letters/numbers from a string) but I couldn't find anything when I looked.  Perhaps there is no easy way built into Ruby because it's needed so infrequently?

Comment: I think this is an easy way, because you just need to apply a regex for numbers and hyphens, and then do the next substitution, also you could try with a more solid regex to catch those "double quotes" skipping the next substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#tr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-tr) instead of `gsub`, as `tr` is much faster than `gsub`:

```
arr.select { |x| x.tr!('\\\"',''); x unless x.empty? }.join(",")
```

Comment: It's getting blank undefined method for an array formed as `a = ["\"-6,\", \"\\\"-3-\\\", \\\"1\\\"\", \"\\\"3-\\\", \\\"5\\\"\", \"\\\"7-\\\", \\\"11\\\"\", \"\\\"14-\\\", \\\"15\\\"\", \"\\\"17-\\\", \\\"20\\\"\""]`.

Comment: i think its a ruby version issue, blank? works in my irb ruby 2.1.1p76, but not running on ideone, anyways my purpose can be solved using `empty?` also. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `empty` did the trick, but also it returns the "double-quotes" within the result.

Comment: this input is not valid as this contains single string as input, even your code wont give the answer, each element must of the form string containg \ and " inside it

Comment: Take it easy bro.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array like:

`Arr = [-6, -3-, 1, 3-, 5, 7-, 11, 14-, 15, 17-, 20]`

So try `join` method:

`Arr.join(',')`
Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
myArray.map { |item| item.gsub(/\\|"/, "") }.join(",").gsub(",,", ",")
```

Comment: I faced the same problem with the double comma.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma You are right, can't get rid of double comma in one step. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastiánPalma plz have look at my solution, tackled double comma issue with `select` Thanks